# A similar code for Ctype for c#

Tags: c#

This code is in `VB.NET`

```
Dim obj As MyObject = CType(row.DataBoundItem, MyObject)
```

I want a similar code for `c#`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myObject = (MyObject)row.DataBoundItem;
```

Or a bit safer way:

```
var myObject = row.DataBoundItem as MyObject;

if(myObject != null)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
var obj =(MyObject)row.DataBoundItem;
```

Or this:

```
MyObject obj =(MyObject)row.DataBoundItem;
```